# Create Wufoo webhook with PUT request in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp, webhooks, wufoo

I'm having troubles with building correct [PUT request](http://wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/webhooks/put/) to the Wufoo.

In all my attempts I see the same error:

`404 A WebHook must contain a url parameter.`

Here is the version with JSON data type:

```
<cfset local.action = "forms/#local.formHash#/webhooks.json" />

<cfset local.request = {"url" : local.webHookURL, "handshakeKey" : local.webHookKey} />

<cfset local.request["handshakeKey"] = local.webHookKey />

<cfhttp url="#local.baseURL##local.action#" method="put" username="#local.apiKey#" password="#local.apiPass#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json; charset=UTF-8" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#SerializeJSON(local.request)#" />
</cfhttp>
```

Same failure when using `file`:

```
<cfset local.action = "forms/#local.formHash#/webhooks.json" />

<cfset local.request = {"url" : local.webHookURL, "handshakeKey" : local.webHookKey} />

<cffile action="write" file="#GetTempDirectory()#webhook.json" output="#SerializeJSON(local.request)#">

<cfhttp url="#local.baseURL##local.action#" method="put" username="#local.apiKey#" password="#local.apiPass#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json; charset=UTF-8" />
    <cfhttpparam type="file" mimetype="application/json" name="json" file="#GetTempDirectory()#webhook.json" />
</cfhttp>
```

---

UPDATE:

To make the code working in ACF (my code works in Railo only) use this syntax for request:

```
<cfset local.request = {} />
<cfset local.request["url"] = local.webHookURL />
<cfset local.request["handshakeKey"] = local.webHookKey />
```

Both methods should produce same JSON with case-sensitive keys.

---

Also I've tried the XML data type:

```
<cfset local.action = "forms/#local.formHash#/webhooks.xml" />

<cfsavecontent variable="putXML">
<cfoutput>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WebHookPutRequest>
<url>#XMLFormat(local.webHookURL)#</url>
<handshakeKey>#XMLFormat(local.webHookKey)#</handshakeKey>
</WebHookPutRequest>
</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cffile action="write" file="#GetTempDirectory()#webhook.xml" output="#Trim(putXML)#">

<cfhttp url="#local.baseURL##local.action#" method="put" username="#local.apiKey#" password="#local.apiPass#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#putXML#" />
</cfhttp>
```

Here I'm not sure if my XML is correct, though for JSON everything should be fine.

Any ideas what's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wufoo [asks for](http://wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/webhooks/put/#putParams) the parameters to be "be passed as post parameters to the Web Hook API". Try using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding for the body of the request. In ColdFusion, you can do this with `<cfhttpparam type="FormField" />`.

```
<cfhttpparam type="FormField" name="url" value="#local.webHookURL#" />
<cfhttpparam type="FormField" name="handshakeKey" value="#local.webHookKey#" />
```

However, ColdFusion rejects this technique with `PUT` methods. You can encode the body yourself using:

```
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" />
<cfhttpparam type="body" value="url=#UrlEncode(local.webHookURL)#&handshakeKey=#UrlEncode(local.webHookKey)#" />
```

Comment: Related question: how would I send the `hash` attribute with `DELETE` reqest? `body` type does not work for DELETE, can't get `formField` working too. See this doc http://wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/webhooks/delete/

Comment: ColdFusion understands `type="FormField"` only for `POST` requests. It is acceptable to include bodies in `DELETE` requests just as in `PUT` requests (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request), but you will have to use the same technique to include the body as you do for including bodies in a `PUT` request. If you need bodies of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then you should (in ColdFusion) use the technique described in this answer.

Comment: Filed as bug for you: http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=84729 vote it up!

Comment: @Sergii I re-read your last comment ... maybe there's nothing you can do directly in CF. Try using a Java library directly? http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/ was the first Google result.

Comment: @Justice, I've talked to the Wufoo developers and they agreed that they should not require any fields passing to the `DELETE` request because it has all needed into (form and webhook hashes) included into the URL. So now it is fixed and works perfectly with `cfhttp`. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

In ColdFusion, generally, variable names are case-insensitive and uppercase.

```
<cfset local.request = {
  url = local.webHookURL,
  handshakeKey = local.webHookKey
} />
```

This gives you a struct with keys `URL` and `HANDSHAKEKEY`.

On the Web, presumably including with the Wufoo REST API, keys are case-sensitive. In this case, Wufoo [accepts](http://wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/webhooks/put/#putParams) keys `url`, `handshakeKey`, and `metadata` - *in that casing*.

In ColdFusion, associative-array notation with struct puts (assignments) lets you keep the precise casing you want.

```
<cfset local.request = { } />
<cfset local.request["url"] = local.webHookURL />
<cfset local.request["handshakeKey"] = local.webHookKey />
```

This gives you a struct with keys `url` and `handshakeKey`.

Comment: This advice does not really applicable here. Please see updated posting -- notes about Railo vs ACF.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with this api but should the url, handshakekey, etc be form post params?

> The following parameters must be
>   passed as post parameters to the Web
>   Hook API
>
> url - this required parameter
>   represents the URL on your server that
>   the Web Hook will call when a new
>   entry is submitted. We do validate the
>   URL and reject malformed URLs.
>
> handshakeKey - this optional parameter
>   is described in the Web Hook
>   integration getting started
>   documentation.
>
> metadata=true - this optional value
>   parameter the Web Hook to send along
>   form/field

The way I read that, it looks like they are asking 
 for each of the params.

The error is suggesting it can't find the URL param, maybe that is it.

Comment: It does not work either when using `<cfhttpparam type="url"` or `<cfhttpparam type="formfield"`. Not sure if this is applicable for PUT at all.