# How to pass parameters in cfhttp for put requests in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfhttp

I need to make a `PUT` request to an API using `cfhttp`. That API expects parameters in FORM scope. But as with PUT request ColdFusion does not send the parameters in FORM scope [Adobe Bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3537036) How can I successfully execute this call?

I have gone through the Stackoverflow [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980064/create-wufoo-webhook-with-put-request-in-coldfusion) , but not able to make successful call to the API. It is showing `The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: cfhttp`.
I have tried increasing the time limit also still its not working.

I am using ColdFusion 10.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't provided your code nor stated why the linked SO question doesn't work.  
Also, the [forum thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5204923) linked on the bug report has [another workaround](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5204923#5204923) - you've not mentioned if you tried that.

Comment: @PeterBoughton: Please check the new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243896/issue-with-put-request-in-coldfusion-10